# Why are items missing from System Settings; how do I get them back?

Tags: xfce, system-settings, gnome-control-center

My settings window currently looks like this:

[image: enter link description here]

Obviously, a lot of items should be there and they aren't. They have been present before in XFCE and in Unity. I've seen other questions about losing System Settings completely, but both `gnome-control-center` and `unity-desktop` are completely installed and up to date on my system.

What files/permissions affect what appears here, how might I resolve this?

Comment: This is very similar to what I have in `gnome-control-center` here on `Xfce`. You have a lot of settings in `xfce4-settings-manager`. But you are looking for restoring all the options in `gnome-control-center`, correct?

Comment: That's right. This is an old issue now (I'm not using xfce any more) but that was the nature of the problem I was having then.

Comment: I never found a solution.

Comment: Yes, this is a curious issue. I always assumed that things were missing because I didn't have much of Gnome installed. But maybe something else is wrong here.

Comment: Does the following address your issue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/397077/system-settings-option-is-missing?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old answer, but I ran into it while googling the same issue -- you can restore items to the gnome-control-center or unity-control-center when under xfce by going to /usr/share/applications/ and editing the *-panel.desktop files, adding ";XFCE" to the "OnlyShowIn" line.

I recommend doing this for the gnome-bluetooth-panel.desktop and the gnome-datetime-panel.desktop files if you're using the indicator applet under XFCE -- it'll let you change bluetooth devices and the clock settings.

Answer (score 0):

Another necropost, but I think the above answer is wrong.

In both Xfce and Unity (but not Gnome) you can control what appears in the settings panel by adding to the `Categories` in the `.desktop` file for whatever utility you want to add.

#### Example

I installed Xfce on regular Ubuntu 16.04, but noticed that the Settings panel in a live usb session of Xubuntu 16.04 was different. One thing missing in my setup was *Language Support*. I looked for *Language Support* (actually *Tacaíocht Teanga* in my case) in `/usr/share/applications` with a root file manager and opened it in a text editor. I then changed the `Categories` line:

*Before*

`Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;DesktopSettings;X-GNOME-Settings-Panel;X-Unity-Settings-Panel;X-GNOME-PersonalSettings`

*After*

`Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;DesktopSettings;X-GNOME-Settings-Panel;X-Unity-Settings-Panel;X-GNOME-PersonalSettings;X-XFCE-SettingsDialog;X-XFCE-PersonalSettings`

#### Categories

**All sections** of the settings panel require:

- *Xfce:* Settings;X-XFCE-SettingsDialog
- *Unity:* Settings;X-Unity-Settings-Panel

**Personal**

- *Xfce:* X-XFCE-PersonalSettings
- *Unity:* X-GNOME-PersonalSettings

**Hardware**

- *Xfce:* X-XFCE-HardwareSettings
- *Unity:* HardwareSettings

**System**

- *Xfce:* X-XFCE-SystemSettings
- *Unity:* X-GNOME-SystemSettings

**Other**

- *Xfce:* If no section is specified the icon will appear in the *Other* section
- *Unity:* Much more complicated! If you look at standard Gnome/Unity Settings .desktop files they have extra lines giving a keyword that (I think) is used for localisation, e.g. for *Language Support* (language-selector.desktop)
  `X-GNOME-Settings-Panel=language`
  `X-Unity-Settings-Panel=language`
  If you add the name you want to appear to an `X-Unity-Settings-Panel=` line, it will appear under *Other*. If you don’t include this line the *Other* section will appear but the icon will not. For other sections, it doesn’t matter if you include this or not.

**Syntax:** although you often see these lines ending in a semi-colon, it is only required to *separate* each category with a semi-colon.

#### Command line

In a GUI file manager `.desktop` files appear with the `Name=` field name as their filename, not their real filename. So to find the right file to edit from the command line you’d have to do something like…

```bash
sean@nung:/usr/share/applications$ grep "Language Support" *.desktop
language-selector.desktop:Name=Language Support
sean@nung:/usr/share/applications$ sudo nano language-selector.desktop
```

#### Problems

Although it’s unlikely to happen very often, the .desktop files in `/usr/share/applications` can be overwritten when an app is updated or the system is upgraded.

For Xfce the solution is simple: copy the files you want to change to `~/.local/share/applications` and make your changes to *those* files. They will override the global ones.

For Unity it’s not so simple. To be added to the settings panel the file must exist in `/usr/share/applications`. You can still *move* the files to `~/.local/share/applications` (for ease of editing/storage) and link them back to `/usr/share/applications`. The links will still potentially get blitzed, but you’ll still have your modified files to relink.

For Unity the local .desktop files need to be **executable**.