# System-Settings option is missing

Tags: 12.04, system-settings

[image]

I no longer get the system-settings option on my ubuntu 12.04. I have earlier used it several times without any problem. I am not aware which action could have caused this problem but I don't remember uninstalling or deleting any package recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

The above command will install everything, which comes as default settings(software center,system settings)

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

This will install system-settings option